# How to increase connections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I start MongoDB this way by running a script startmongo.sh which will start all the below in order

```
./mongodb1.sh
./mongodb2.sh
./mongod3_arbiter.sh
```

Each mongodb1.sh , mongodb2.sh , mongodb3_arbiter.sh  consists of code as

```
mongod --config mongod1.conf

mongod --config mongod2.conf

mongod --config mongod3_arbiter.conf
```

I want to increase the connection limit to 10000 , so i wanted to specify attribute ulimit -n 10000

My question is do i need to specify this attribute all the above conf files ??

Right now the conf consists of

```
replSet = test
fork    = true
port    = 27017
dbpath  = /mongologs/mongodb3
logpath = /mongologs/mongo/mongodb3
rest = true
```

Please let me know , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

H friend, I think you need to set maxpoolSize.

Please have a look at [mongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-pool-options)

There described like

```
uri.maxPoolSize¶
The maximum number of connections in the connection pool. The default value is 100.
```

Answer (score 0):

These are set in `/etc/limits.conf` (debian based) or `/etc/security/limits.conf` (redhat based) depending on what linux distribution you have.

You are looking for the `nofile` attribute.

```
<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
*             soft    nofile         10000
*             hard    nofile         10000
```